# How can I open a new browser tab in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

When I run a PHP script in Eclipse environment, I can select different browsers to render my page and can get different results.

But the results are still all shown in the browser output window in eclipse itself.

How can I prompt eclipse to actually open a new tab in the browser itself with the php page. I know it can be done by "external tools", just dont know how exactly to configure it.

Comment: tag your question with "php" to get some responses

Answer (score 1):

From the main menu -> Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Browser -> select the external browser radio button and your preferred browser.

enjoy ;)
Roy

Comment: Nope! that doesnt launch a "chrome" or "firefox" external instance.It merely renders using that browser within eclipse output only. Here is what I want to do : use firebug in the generated output.Have to launch a real Firefox tab for that. This doesnt do that.

Comment: make sure you have  "use external browser" selected