# Open a new internal web browser tab in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How do I open a new internal web browser tab in Eclipse?

There are similar questions here ([How can I open a new browser tab in Eclipse PDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903197/how-can-i-open-a-new-browser-tab-in-eclipse-pdt) or [Eclipse - open a new browser tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272546/eclipse-open-a-new-browser-tab?rq=1)) which consistently fail to answer this properly.

The issue is: You want a new (=additional, probably second or third) browser tab with an internal web browser functionality as part of the Eclipse window. Or, alternatively, a second or third tab inside of the existing internal browser.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no menu option to create more that th one web browser view. A plug-in can create more that one view programmatically.

Comment: If you have opened a (HTML) file with the _Web Browser_ editor(!) you can use _Window > Editor > Clone_ to create an additional _Web Browser_ editor tab. Please note, this does not work with the _Internal Web Browser_ view(!).

Comment: See also [Eclipse bug 158012](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=158012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously not possible and not intended:

[Bug 158012 - [Browser] Internal web browser view should not be singleton](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=158012)

- `Status:  RESOLVED WONTFIX` (2008)
- `Platform:  3.3`  (~ 2006)